# Circle inside a square, determine if a given point in the square lies within the circle

Tags: math, geometry

I am working on a project where I have a square screen, but want to put a circular cover over it in the center. I am trying to figure out how to determine if a given pixel I am trying to use on the screen is visible with the circular cover over it. So given the pixel coordinates of x0, y0, how do I determine if the point lies within the circle and will be visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the distance from the centrepoint of the circle. If it is equal or less than the radius of the circle then it will be inside it.

Comment: formula is root of ((x2-x1)^2  + (y2-y1)^2)

Comment: Sweet, I was 100% overcomplicating it. That works great!!!!!!

Comment: An obvious improvement is to compare the **squared distance** with the squared radius, instead of comparing the distance with the radius. In other words, test for `(x-x_center)^2 + (y-y_center)^2 < R^2` rather than `sqrt((x-x_center)^2 + (y-y_center)^2) < R`; there is no need for a costly computation of sqrt(). Additionally, be careful with the symbol `^`. In most programming languages, this symbol stands for *bitwise xor*, **not** for exponentiation. Squaring a number `x` can usually be written `x**2`, or `pow(x,2)`, or most simply `x*x`.